# After updating to 18.04, VSync locks frame rate to 40 FPS instead of 60

Tags: games, framerate

Programs that previously ran at 60 FPS now are locked at 40 FPS. Disabling VSync produces the proper frame rate.

My refresh rate is set to 60.02 Hz in the settings menu.

I'm running on a laptop with integrated Intel graphics.

Comment: Almost the same here, except I'm locked to 48 FPS.

Comment: One sort of solution that works for me is to set the FPS to 119.94 in GNOME settings, then games run at 60 FPS (yeah, for some reason I have a 120 Hz option... running xrandr shows the refresh rate to be 59.97 when I use this setting.)

Comment: I looked at the settings and found I have a 40.04 Hz refresh rate option, but changing to it (and back) still results in the frame rate being locked at 40.

Comment: Did you try every possible refresh rate that xrandr lists? Might not work for you but one of the 4 works for me (59.97.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using the steps found in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227894

My `xrandr` output only listed one display mode: `1920x1080     60.02*+  40.03`, which wasn't producing the desired frame rate.

First I ran `gtf 1920 1080 60`, which produced this output: `"1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync`.

I used that to add a new display mode to `xrandr`: `xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync`/

I then added it as  a possible option for my laptop's screen: `xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"`. At this point the screen flickered, but still hadn't switched.

Finally, I forced the display mode to be the output for my screen: `xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"`. After this, my refresh rate was back to 60 as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in Linux kernel 4.14.
Here are a couple of threads that discuss it:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/31999

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/poor-opengl-performance-on-linux-4-14/35453/150